# ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios8, build-error, xcode6.4

I am a beginner in iOS development. I am developing an application in Xcode 6.4 and I want create a SQlite database in Project. When I am trying to add constant, connection manager and query helper classes in bundle file and build project, I have the following error:

```
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the exact logcat output or screenshot?

Comment: @Sushrita I have post screenshot.

Comment: I included the image in the post instead of having a link.

Comment: @Tunaki : you have posted an image of *plain text*! Why would you not simply copy & paste the plain text?

Comment: You have one error (shown), preceded by 11 warnings (not shown). The warnings may be relevant to your issue, you should deal with them first, or at least post them too (in *plain text*).

Comment: Where is `NotificationTable` *declared*?  In an include file without `extern`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all comment on my question,

I found the solution of  *ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64*, at time of declaration of constant for table name variable, I have used **NSObject** class file for constant declaration,However this is not correct way to declare constant variable so I used **"Header File"** and declared constant variable as like below ,

```
 #define registration_table @"registration_table"
```

**UPDATED**

If we **import** .m file instead of .h file that time also **we facing  duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64** exception, check import file .

Hope so it will help to someone

Answer (score 0):

duplicate symbols 'NotificationTable' in both files, in my case ,just rename one of them and it works!